# How to integrate out linear terms in Lagrangian?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, standard-model, higgs, interactions, effective-field-theory

Consider, for example, the Higgs Lagrangian for leptons

$$L = Y_{yukawa} \bar{L} H e_R + h.c.$$
If I want to integrate out the Higgs field, what should I do?

As it is linear, if I solve the Euler-Lagrange's equations I find only that $Y_{yukawa} \bar{L} e_R =0$. And by the partition function method, I haven't found how to evaluate a linear integral in a field.

Appreciate.

Comment: Hi José Psicodélico. Welcome to Phys.SE. What about the usual kinetic & potential terms for the Higgs field? Why are they not mentioned in the OP?

Comment: Hi. I just wanted to give an example for the case where a field appears linearly.

Comment: Now that you mention it, in the case of the Higgs field, if I wrote the other terms I think I could isolate by finding the equations of motion.

Answer (score 1):

There won't be any simple answer to this process. The resulting effective action  will be minus the logarithm of  the functional determinant of the Dirac  operator that appears in the action. Only if the space-time variation of $H$ is slow compared to the scale set by the fermion mass-gap can you get a good approximation.